# How can i fetch the div html of particular class in this case

Tags: jquery

On click of the tab (Qty 1 Or Qty 2 ) in this case .

How can i fetch the div popup_content div data ??

I have tried this way  but i am getting undefined

```
$(document).on('click', '.tabclcik', function (e) {
    var data = $(this).find('.popup_content').html();
    alert(data);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5axh3xzs/5/

Could anybody please let me know how to fetch this ??

Comment: `.popup_content` isn't a child of the `.tabclcik` element, so find won't work. Given there's only 1 `.popup_content` element, you can just select it directly: `$('.popup_content').html();`

Comment: I added it as an answer for you.

Comment: Did u try this    http://jsfiddle.net/5axh3xzs/9/
    
    $(document).on('click', '.tabclcik', function (e) {
    var data = $("#testdiv").html();
    alert(data);
});

Answer (score 2):

Use the index of the tab to target the content with the same index:

```
var idx = $(this).index();
var data = $(this).closest('div').find(".popup_content li").eq(idx).html();
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/5axh3xzs/10/)**

http://api.jquery.com/eq

Comment: Nice answer, +1. Downvote isn't me, in case you were wondering

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but you can use siblings() instead of find():

```
var data = $(this).closest('div').siblings('.popup_content').html();
```

Comment: `.popup_content` isn't a sibling of `.tabclcik` in the posted example